# Firestore Stripe error "Could not serialize object. Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead."

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to integrate Stripe with Firebase and Android to make payments.After searching on the internet here is how I try to send the token to the server:

```
   if (cardForm.isValid()) {
                String cardNumber = cardForm.getCardNumber();
                String cvv =  cardForm.getCvv();
                Integer month = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(cardForm.getExpirationMonth()));
                Integer year = new Integer(Integer.parseInt( cardForm.getExpirationYear()));

                 Card card = Card.create(cardNumber , month,  year, cvv);

                stripe.createCardToken(card, new ApiResultCallback<Token>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                        DocumentReference tokenRef;
                        tokenRef = db.collection("stripe_customers").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("tokens").document();


                        tokenRef.set(token).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Token successfully added to database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Unfortunately, when I try to set token data into firestore, the following error occurs:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object. Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead (found in field 'card.loggingTokens$stripe_release')

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: While your error is related to storage in firebase, and not Stripe, you should avoid handling card numbers etc manually. Instead, consider implementing payments with the Stripe Android SDK to collect payment details: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android

Comment: Show us the content of your model class.

Comment: Do you refer to the Card class. If not, which one are you referring to?